# Creating an alias using the current directory using cmder

Tags: command-line-interface, alias, cmder

I'm using cmder for Windows (based on ConEmu) and I've been using the following syntax to create alias' for my projects.

```
alias myProject=cd c:/xampp/htdocs/myProject/wp-content/themes/myProject
```

How can I create an alias using the current directory (rather than having to manually `pwd`, copy that, then paste it into the alias command?

Comment: Old one, but though to add this here.
@Maximus Unfortunately that doesn't work. For example `echo %cd%` in an alias will echo out `%cd%` not the working dir.

Comment: Try batch files. Anyway, the question does not relate to cmder or ConEmu.